# Erro ao printar mensagem dentro de condição

Tags: c, condição, printf

Quando digito qualquer valor que não seja 2 valores iguais, a mensagem "Valor digitado invalido!" é mostrada de qualquer forma. Alguém sabe por que?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

    int main(){
        int x, y;

        printf("Digite 2 valores: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

        if(x>y)
            printf("O valor %d eh maior que %d", x, y);
        if(x<y)
            printf("O valor %d eh menor que %d", x, y);
        if(x==y)
            printf("O valor %d eh igual ao valor %d", x, y);
        else
            printf("Valor digitado invalido!");     

        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar `else if` invés de repetir o `if`

corrigindo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

    int main(){
        int x, y;

        printf("Digite 2 valores: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

        if(x>y)
            printf("O valor %d eh maior que %d", x, y);
        else if(x<y)
            printf("O valor %d eh menor que %d", x, y);
        else if(x==y)
            printf("O valor %d eh igual ao valor %d", x, y);
        else
            printf("Valor digitado invalido!");

        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```